# How to prevent large files upload to Azure via Put Blob

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-blob-storage

Because of bandwidth issue, I'm currently sending my files directly to Azure blob storage.

But I don't want anyone with the access token to upload any file that is too large. According to Microsoft docs: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob)

> Note that the storage emulator only supports blob sizes up to 2 GB.

Is there any way that I can prevent user to upload file which is larger than 10MB to my blob storage via Azure settings or policies.

Comment: No such feature, you can only achieve it through code.

Comment: So you are uploading blob with storage emulator? Or other ways, code,storage explorer.

Comment: I'm uploading with storage emulator

Answer (score 0):

Please notice that the limit you show is about the storage emulator.(This is a local virtual storage)

For real Azure blob Storage, please refer to this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#azure-blob-storage-limits

And about your requirement, Azure Storage does not have such a feature that allows you to customize the size of the uploaded file, you can only design it in the code.